# How to set an invalid time for a Date?

Tags: java, android

In programming,  we have standard ways to specify 'red flags' or corner points or invalid values.

For instance,

NONE = -1

EOF = -1

emptyString = ""

How does one set an invalid value for a java.util.Date?

Is assigning null the best answer? Note that even String has "".

Date aVar = [red flag or invalid value]

Comment: the empty string is not an invalid value

Comment: These "invalid values" are not really standard values. There are no general standard "empty" or "invalid" values for any purpose. For example, if you need to represent "none", then there's nothing that says you have to use the value -1 for that. Choose whatever works for your particular application.

Comment: @PhilippSander and Jesper They are valid as datatypes but are commonly used as red flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use for times/dates

```
long lastUsed = Long.MIN_VALUE;
Date expireTime = new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE);
LocalDate maxDate = LocalDate.MAX; // Java 8.
```

For an "invliad" string I have used

```
String invalid = "\uFFFF";
```

The \uFFFF is defined as a non-character and is greater than all other Strings (which don't start with this character, if you ignore code points)

Comment: excellent! I shall use  `nextTime = new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE);`

Comment: @likejiujitsu Whether you use MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is perfect for this case.

Comment: Can you go in a bit more detail about why it's perfect?